# Gmail log in from foreign location

Tags: gmail, google

My friend and I share a gmail account.  She is from the US and is on business in Kuwait.  Gmail wouldn't let her log in from the foreign location.  Can I change settings so that gmail will allow her to log in and send emails?

Comment: I think she should be fine if she just verify her account with her mobile.

Comment: You are also in the US I assume? Was your friend not challenged to identify herself? Or what other error did gmail report?

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of your inbox in Gmail there is something that says "Last account activity:"
Directly under that there is a link "Details"
If you click this link it should pop open a new window with the activity log.
At the bottom of the log it will give you the option you are looking for.
"Alert preference: Show an alert for unusual activity. Change"

If you request that an alert be generated,
it is my understanding that "strange" access attempts may be prevented.

Obviously, there are safety implications to disabling such an alert.